# Android app closes unfortunately

Tags: android

I am using eclipse with libGdx framework... And Everything is set... But only when i am Run android through emulator after launching when i click on App icon it gives me a message "UNFORTUNATELY APP-NAME HAS STOPPED"... Please tell me why this is happening... Because same code works when i run as Desktop java Application through Eclipse... Please help me out... Thanks...

### LOG CAT DETAILS :

```
08-09 19:30:45.729: W/dalvikvm(747): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/badlogic/drop/MainActivity; (20)
08-09 19:30:45.739: W/dalvikvm(747): Link of class 'Lcom/badlogic/drop/MainActivity;' failed
08-09 19:30:45.759: D/AndroidRuntime(747): Shutting down VM
08-09 19:30:45.759: W/dalvikvm(747): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.badlogic.drop/com.badlogic.drop.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.badlogic.drop.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.badlogic.drop-2.apk
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.badlogic.drop.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.badlogic.drop-2.apk
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
08-09 19:30:45.779: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  ... 11 more
08-09 19:35:53.845: I/Process(747): Sending signal. PID: 747 SIG: 9
08-09 19:37:20.125: E/Trace(958): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-09 19:37:20.225: W/dalvikvm(958): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/badlogic/drop/MainActivity; (20)
08-09 19:37:20.255: W/dalvikvm(958): Link of class 'Lcom/badlogic/drop/MainActivity;' failed
08-09 19:37:20.265: D/AndroidRuntime(958): Shutting down VM
08-09 19:37:20.265: W/dalvikvm(958): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.badlogic.drop/com.badlogic.drop.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.badlogic.drop.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.badlogic.drop-2.apk
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.badlogic.drop.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.badlogic.drop-2.apk
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
08-09 19:37:20.306: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  ... 11 more
08-09 19:37:24.495: I/Process(958): Sending signal. PID: 958 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Your project seems to be messed up. I suggest you recreate it from scratch. The log you pasted in contains a very detailed description of why it is not working. Try to read it, it's there for you to help.

Comment: In One more Case Log CAT Details Is :

Comment: 08-09 19:49:41.670: I/dalvikvm(800): Failed resolving Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication; interface 91 'Lcom/badlogic/gdx/Application;'
08-09 19:49:41.670: W/dalvikvm(800): Link of class 'Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication;' failed
08-09 19:49:41.670: W/dalvikvm(800): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/badlogic/drop/MainActivity; (118)
08-09 19:49:41.670: W/dalvikvm(800): Link of class 'Lcom/badlogic/drop/MainActivity;' failed

Comment: You should edit your original question to include that Logcat. It is very hard to read as a comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you renamed your mainactivity class and didn't update the android manifest.